# Изменить дизайн блока, если он вышел за пределы видимости окна браузера

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

Возможно ли на чистом css без использования javascript, ну или хотя бы без использования offset, scrollTop (не работают во время скролла на ios) изменить стиль блока, к примеру, удалить background-image, который стал выходит за пределы видимости окна браузера при скролле?

Comment: @MrAdrianS, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

`document.documentElement` содержит значение прокрутки, если стоит правильный `DOCTYPE`. Это работает во всех браузерах, кроме Safari/Chrome.

Safari/Chrome используют вместо этого `document.body` (это баг в Webkit).